# AWS Lambda: index.handler is undefined or not exported

Tags: aws-lambda

This is the message i receive while testing my aws lambda funcion.
my file structure:

```
aws-lambda-test-mysql/
├─ node_modules/
├─ my-lib-functions/
│  ├─ mysqlFun.js
│  ├─ readme.md
├─ test.js
├─ package.json
├─ README.md
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you lack of an index.js file, that's standard for aws lambda.